# CMFCPropertyGridProperty and CCombobox binding

Tags: c++, mfc, combobox, ccombobox

I was developing a MFC application and I noticed that the combobox which is created after the use of the method `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::AddOption()` does not have as many functionalities as the `CCombobox` class. Is there a way to bind objects from these two classes? (Better saying, is there a way to add a `CCombobox` object in one `CMFCPropertyGrid` subitem?)

If it isn't possible, is there an alternative way to use a combobox with the same (or just some) functionalities provided by the `CCombobox` class?

Answer (score 0):

Check `CreateCombo` protected member of `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` class.
You should create the new `CComboBox` object within this overloaded member function and initialize it with `Create`. The property is responsible for the final (not so sure) clean.

**UPD:**

I have faced the problem with a combo box inside the property grid class some time ago. If you want to catch some extended `CComboBox` events or call `CComboBox` methods inside or outside your property class, you should define your own `CreateCombo` method inside your own property and call `CreateCombo` method of the base `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` class. It returns the valid `CComboBox*` pointer. Store this pointer inside your property member and then you can do anything with it.